# Struts 2 get parameter in Action class

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I use Struts 2 and Ajax. I am not able to get parameter in Action class. I have a form like this:

```
<s:form id="form" onSubmit="sendAjaxRequest();">
    <s:textfield  name="libelle" label="Libelle" />
    <s:textfield name="id" label="id" />
    <s:submit value="Valider" />
    <s:reset value="Effacer" />
</s:form>
```

When I examine the request which is sent in HTTP Reader :

```
Content-length contains libelle=Test&id=13
```

My request is good !

In my action class :

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String libelle;
    private Integer id;

    public String getLibelle() {
        return auteur;
    }

    public void setLibelle(String libelle) {
        this.libelle = libelle;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("Libelle " + libelle);
        System.out.println("Libelle " + this.libelle);
    }
}
```

In my Action libelle and this. libelle are null. I don't know if I am making mistakes. If someone could give me help. Thanks.

I found my problem but not a solution. I inspect the html code generated and i see the following one :

```
<form id="form" name="form" action="/path/MyOtherAction.action" method="post" onSubmit="sendAjaxRequest();">
  <table class="wwFormTable">
      <tr>
          <td class="tdLabel"><label for="form_libelle" class="label">Libelle:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="libelle" value="" id="form_libelle"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="tdLabel"><label for="form_id" class="label">id:</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="ide" value="" id="form_id"/></td>
      </tr>
...
          <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="submit" id="form_0" value="Valider"/>
..
          <td colspan="2"><div align="right"><input type="reset" value="Effacer"/>
..
  </table>
</form>
```

So MyOtherAction is executed first before my sendAjaxRequest. How to remove action MyOtherAction in my form ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to supply an action that works, that would not compile because auteur is not defined for the class... so considering you are having a run time error it's pretty hard to tell what's happening.

Comment: Quaternion i correct, it was a mistake.

Comment: Please create a working example and then cut and paste it, I can visually tell that this will fail too.

Comment: can try with `return endAjaxRequest();`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you could try with [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/). This way `MyOtherAction` won't execute on submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the submit event on the form like this :

```
$(document).ready( function() {    
    $("#form").submit( function() {
        sendAjaxRequest();
        return false; // it will stop the submit process
    });
});
```

When the event is catch, the `sendAjaxRequest()` function be execute and because the function return false, the form will not be submit to `/path/MyOtherAction.action`.